# C++ for condition string[i]

Tags: c++, string, conditional-statements

I have found something like this on google:

```
for(int i=0;someString[i];++i){
    //code to do
}
```

but I cant figure out what someString[i] means. It shouldnt be boolean expresion so how does compiler know when to end for cycle? Maybe this is trivial question but I am pretty new to c++.

Thank you in forward

Comment: How is `someString` declared? We cannot answer unless you tell (or we guess) how!

Comment: According to C standard String termination is `\0` is always zero where it uses ASCII or any other code. http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap7/subsection2.1.1.2.html

Answer (score 4):

If `someString` is an array containing anything that can be converted to a `bool`, then accessing its elements serves as a condition. For example, if it is a `char` array, then all elements bar `'\0'` will evaluate to `true`. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  char someString[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  for (auto c : someString)
    std::cout << bool(c) << std::endl;
}
```

Your loop will stop upon encountering the first falsy element.

Comment: thanks so basicaly if I reach end of string it ondition will be false?

Comment: @horin You won't enter the loop for the last element in the string (the 0)

Comment: @horin if `someString` is a null-terminated character string, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `someString` is a `char*` or `const char*`, this loop stops when it reaches the terminating NUL byte.

That's because each `char` called `someString[i]` is a number, and numbers convert to `false` if and only if they are 0. NUL is 0.